# Why is the content in my scrollview showing up with a y-offset when I haven't changed any offset properties?

Tags: android

It happens in both the Eclipse UI designer and when the app in running. Seems to only happen when I add multiple `<include>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this will happen if you include a layout that contains an EditText view that contains a `<requestFocus>` tag. The ScrollView automatically scrolls to the last item with the `<requestFocus>` tag.